# Button states pressed / selected (Android)

Tags: buttons

I'm working on a Android project. I need to design 5 states of a button:

- normal
- focused
- selected
- pressed
- disabled.

I do not understand the difference between pressed and selected. I have found that explanation:

> Pressed – when a widget such as a button is clicked
>   Selected – when a widget is activated, such as the active tab on a tab control.

If a button is clicked/pressed, it is activated, not selected, that is right?

Unfortunately I'm working without the Android SDK for testing.

Can anyone explain that to me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html

It is the official documentation for **TouchFeedback**. There is no official *selected* state - at least for regular buttons. You can read all definitions for the different states there. It is about **illumination** and **visibility** grade.

Best regards
Vince

---

**edit:**

[image]

In this example the first one is the **selected state** for the **RadioButton**, the second one the **normal state**

As the name says, it is about the *selection* - there are *selected items* and *unselected items* what works for tabs and much more, too (but **not for simple buttons** - that is why you can not find a selected state in Google's documentation.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The Link to the developer site I did read before, but is was not helpful enough to me. Your Comment that you have never heard of selected state, was very helpful for me, thanks a lot,

Comment: Hi Vince,but I am still a little bit confused..

Comment: Hi Reggie! You' re welcome. Is it clear now? So just for summary: There is no selected state for regular buttons, but for tabs, radio-buttons and toggle-buttons and other elements - those which can be selected. For the toggle-button for example you might have a colored dot in that circle for being selected.